# syntax of binary:split with multiple patterns

Tags: erlang

What is the correct syntax when we use multiple patterns ?

```
test3()->
    test4(<<"1234567890">>).
test4(A)->
    X = binary:split(A,[<<"3">>,<<"8">>]),
    X.
```

`[<<"12">>,<<"4567890">>]`

I was expected 3 elements!

Comment: I must add [global] after the patterns !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get 3 elements, you should use the split/3 function and to specify the global option ("Repeats the split until the Subject is exhausted"):

```
binary:split(<<"1234567890">>,[<<"3">>,<<"8">>],[global]).
```

and you'll get:

```
[<<"12">>,<<"4567">>,<<"90">>]
```

More on this, in the official doc: http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/binary.html#split-3

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you: I found myself ;-)